# Requests in URL monitoring should fail, but don't

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to write a script to Monitor URLs in Windows server using powershell. The below is the script. I used three URLs to see the responses. 
 Expected result is

- `http://google.com` - should fail because the HTTP is going to be redirected to HTTPS, but I got 200 as response.
- `https://google.com` - should be success and it was success.
- `https://yahoo.com` - should fail because the proxy will block the Yahoo.

But the funny thing is I got success for all 3 URLs. `https://google.com` is somewhat acceptable but in case of Yahoo the proxy server is throwing a error page as site is blocked but the below code is taking the proxy error page as success and showing it as success but with an error.

[image]

Please advise me which is the reliable way to get the HTTP response code in PowerShell.

```
$sites = @(
    "http://www.google.com",
    "https://www.google.com",
    "https://www.yahoo.com"
)

foreach ($url in $sites) {
    $HTTP_Request  = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$url")
    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
    $HTTP_Status   = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

    if ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
        Write-Host "$url" " is OK!" 
    } else {
        Write-Host "$url" " may be down, please check!"
    }
    $HTTP_Response.Close()
}
```

Comment: The first one succeeds because you haven't set `$HTTP_Request.AllowAutoRedirect` to `$false`

Comment: If your proxy returns an error page without an error response code (never ceases to amaze me how anyone could mistake that for a good idea) you should reconfigure the proxy to behave correctly. Otherwise you'll have to interpret the actual (HTML) page that is returned.

Comment: What @Ansgar says. You most likely have a malconfigured (or even self-built) proxy server that returns "200 OK - You may not view that page".

Comment: I cannot do any modification in proxy as it is not managed by our team or I cannot request for any modification also. I am attaching the screenshot of error i get. Please suggest how can I manage this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proxy requires authentication, so you don't even get an HTTP response from `https://www.yahoo.com`. Since you didn't provide proxy credentials the call `$req.GetResponse()` throws an error, and the variable `$HTTP_Response` retains its value from the previous iteration (the response from `https://www.google.com`). That's why it seems like you get an OK for that URL.

Catch errors thrown by `GetResponse()` and set `$HTTP_Status` to a value other than 200 in case of an error:

```
foreach ($url in $sites) {
    $HTTP_Request = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    try {
        $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
        $HTTP_Status   = $HTTP_Response.StatusCode.value__
    } catch {
        $HTTP_Status = 0
    } finally {
        if ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) { 
            Write-Host "$url is OK!" 
        } else {
            Write-Host "$url may be down, please check!"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ansgar, Thank you very much. This worked as expected.